# Deshabilitar boton por medio de javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hola amigos lo que ocurre es que en HTML tengo un boton que esta hecho por la etiqueta  y quiero que cuando se seleccione algo este se esconda o se deshabilite. No puedo usar input.

```
<body>
  <select name="tipo"  id="tipo" onChange="todasfun()">
    <option value="" selected>Seleccione</option>
    <option value="9">Finalizada</option>
    <option value="10">Sin finalizar</option>
  </select>
<a type="button" id="btn" href="">boton</a>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

 $("#tipo").change(function() {
  document.getElementById("btn").type = "hidden";
 });


</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Como es una etiqueta, se podria desabilitar con `css` de la siguiente manera:

```js
$("#tipo").change(function() {
  $('#btn').addClass('disabled');
});
```

```css
.disabled{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <select name="tipo" id="tipo">
    <option value="" selected>Seleccione</option>
    <option value="9">Finalizada</option>
    <option value="10">Sin finalizar</option>
  </select>
  <a type="button" id="btn" href="">boton</a>
</body>
```

Por otro lado tengo 2 preguntas:

1. Si tienes ya el evento `onchange`, ¿Porque le pones otro?
2. Si estas utilizando `jQuery`, ¿Porque usas `getElementById` en vez de `$('#')`?

**Referencia**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esto:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


   $("#tipo").change(function(){

     $('#btn').prop("hidden", true); // y en lugar de true, false para volver a mostrar
    //$('#btn').toggle("hidden");//alterna la propiedad hidden cada cambio detectado

   });

});
```